# Table is created but not recognised

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, insert

I have a database called 'SchoolRecords' and I created a table using the following code:

```
Create TABLE tblRoom (
ID nvarchar (2) Primary Key,
RoomType nvarchar (8),
Capacity numeric (3)
)
```

The Table is created because it appears in the object explorer, however when I try to insert information it shows an red line under the table name and when hovering over it, it says 'invalid object name 'tblRoom'. My code is below:

```
insert into tblRoom values ('B115[ca]','LT',100)
insert into tblRoom values ('B206[ca]','CL',36)
```

When exectuting the code this error occurs:

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: to fix the red squigglies you just need to update your intellisense cache. ctrl + shift + r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't the "invalid object name", which could be a false positive error in the designer (it happens).  Your issue is

> String or binary data would be truncated.

You define your ID as `nvarchar (2)`, yet you're trying to stuff a string in there that's way over two characters long:  **'B115[ca]'**.  Either increase the size of your ID to `nvarchar(8)` or greater, or shrink down your ID.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the query takes the same order as the declaration you made when you create the table. With your query you area trying to insert a nvarchar(8) in a nvarchar(2) type column.

The insertion order must be ID, RoomType and Capacity.

The other way of doing this is declarating the order of insert:

```
INSERT INTO tblRoom
(RoomType, ID, Capacity)
VALUES ('B115[ca]','LT',100)
```